# Cakephp how to remove trailing '/' from url for SEO purpose

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I remove trailing '/' from url?

For example I've a url `http://www.example.com/our_story` it delivers our story page. But `http://www.example.com/our_story/` also delivers the same page. But our seo experts says that this is creating duplicate pages in google listing.

My Site is already developed, they are telling me to redirect this URL `http://www.example.com/our_story/` to `http://www.example.com/our_story`. How can achieve this? I think .htaccess should help.

Comment: we use the opposite apprach - always displaying the urls with the trailing slash (as some argue that this was the more correct approach) - either way you can use htaccess to do that

Comment: But this is the requirement for me from my SEO Expert. @mark Can you please give me solution in CAKEPHP I found other .htaccess which they have written for normal php but those are not working when I've used in my cakephp .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a 301 redirect. This isn't exactly a cakePHP issue its more HTAccess.

This link may be helpful.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/%20articles/view/4caea0e1-0e48-4b55-a9ce-46a082f0cb67